# How to extract data from bracket and replace in laravel

Tags: php

My string is

```
"invoice = [[invoice_no]]
customer = [[customer]]
item = [[item]]"
```

How can i do upper string to covert the following with php?

```
"invoice = " $data->invoice_no
"customer = " $data->customer
"item = " $data->item
```

Comment: why you need to do like `$data.invoice_no` , what is `.` dot here ?

Comment: I want to extract invoice_no of $data array from Database.

Comment: if `$data` is an array, then you would want to access it as an array. `$data['invoice_no']`, however, if it's an object, access it as an object. `$data->invoice_no`

Comment: yes. i wrong in usage.

Comment: Why don't you put it into the blade template and binding data by blade guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already created one function for same type of parsing, it replaces `{{item}}` by give data like `$data['item']`. here is example , you can change according to your requirement.

```
<?php
    function putValuesInHTML($html_form,$reportData){
        preg_match_all('/{{([A-Za-z0-9_ ]+?)}}/', $html_form, $fields);
        $arrInHtml = array();
        $valsForHtml = array();
        foreach ($fields[1] as $key => $value) {
            if(isset($reportData[$value])){
                $arrInHtml[] = "{{".$value."}}";
                $valsForHtml[] = $reportData[$value];
            }
        }
        $result = str_replace($arrInHtml,$valsForHtml,$html_form);
        /*Eval start*/
        preg_match_all('/{{=([A-Za-z0-9+\-\/{}* ]+?)=}}/', $result, $evals);
        $arrInHtml = array();
        $valsForHtml = array();
        foreach ($evals[1] as $key => $value) {
            $eval = "00";
            $arrInHtml[] = "{{=".$value."=}}";
            eval("\$eval= ".$value.";");
            $valsForHtml[] = $eval;
        }
        $reportHTML = str_replace($arrInHtml,$valsForHtml,$result);
        return $reportHTML;
    }

$str = "invoice = {{invoice_no}}
customer = {{customer}}
item = {{item}}";
$data = ["invoice_no"=>"111","customer"=>"Niklesh Raut","item"=>"iphone"]    ;
$newStr = putValuesInHTML($str,$data);
echo $newStr;

?>
```

[Live demo](https://eval.in/968423)

Input :

```
invoice = {{invoice_no}}
customer = {{customer}}
item = {{item}}
```

Output for `$data = ["invoice_no"=>"111","customer"=>"Niklesh Raut","item"=>"iphone"]` :

```
invoice = 111
customer = Niklesh Raut
item = iphone
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.